# Date confusion with relationships - start date can be later than end date

Tags: error, relationships, dates

When adding relationships, I have found that the start date entered can be a later date than the end date of the relationship without any error being indicated.

Is this intentional or can I "fix" it so that a user cannot enter a relationship with this error as displayed below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly not intentional.  You can fix it if you're a programmer or have access to one!

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately I am not a programmer - is it worth listing on the bug list?

Comment: @MrsBakesALot You can list it - and it's always possible someone will take it on!  However, as folks say, "CiviCRM is free to use, but not to write."  Most likely this won't be addressed unless someone puts resources - money, or developer time - into it.